# Remove hardcoded urls from htaccess rewriterules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I've got a `.htaccess` with multiple rules and 3 with a hardcoded urls for a Magento shop:

**1)** To remove the port number from the URL, the site is running in a Docker container with Apache and Nginx runs on the host to forward traffic to the right container. For some reason `:80` is added to the url, this rule removes it:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.nl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**2)** Removes the `index.php` from the url:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://domain.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**3)** Redirects `/home` to `/`:

```
redirect 301 /home https://domain.nl
```

Now I'd like to run multiple stores in this Magento installation so multiple domain names are linked to this installation. This `.htaccess` conflicts because of the hardcoded urls. I've tried to make these generic but I end up with 500 errors. How to make these 3 rules generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! After multiple attempts and checking the headers with curl I figured it out. But it's still a little strange configuration because Nginx redirects everything on the host to Apache in the Docker container.

**1)**

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^:]+)(:[0-9]+)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**2)**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**3)**

```
RewriteRule ^home/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [nc,R=301,L]
```